# Infinite looping, and only executing part of the script if first part is true

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I've created a infinite loop that checks for friend requests, if there are any, it accepts them and so the script continues for ever.

See the code here:

```
while True:

    snaps = s.get_snaps()

    for sender in snaps:
        if sender['media_type'] == 3:
            s.add_friend(sender[u'sender'])


    friends = s.get_friends()

    names = []
    for friend in friends:
        if friend['type'] == 0:
            names.append(friend[u'name'])

    print "Amount of confirmed friends:",
    print len(names),
    print "/ 6000"
```

The script works, so far, but not quite the way I want it to.

It keeps printing X / 6000 over and over again, and that's what is bothering me. I only want the script to execute the "print" part, when it actually accepted a / multiple friend request(s)

So this part:

```
print "Amount of confirmed friends:",
print len(names),
print "/ 6000"
```

Can only be printed when someone is actually accepted as a friend, and thus updating the amount of confirmed friends.

I have mixed feelings here, I never went to such great detail in using `if` statements etc.

The scenarios I have considered are:

Putting an if statement where it adds someone, if the result is (good?) it continues to the rest of script.

Or putting an if statement at the bottom just before it prints, saying that if someone is actually added it prints, otherwise it goes back to repeating itself.

A few things to take in mind here, the less requests / activity towards the server of snapchat, the better. So if I could limit it at the start of the script that'd be preferred.

Though I don't know how to do this.

Could someone explain me how I can check if there's someone (or multiple people) found with media_type 3 and if there is, it continues the script. If there's not, it sleeps for a few seconds and goes back to trying again.

I feel like this is a delicate subject, and I'm worried that I will mess my code up, and end up not knowing what the hell I am doing and getting frustrated over it. Before asking I have reached out to Google and TutorialsPoint, but I still haven't been able to apply anything I've read just because I have no clue how.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do here. You are checknig for media type of the snap first, adding the snaps sender as a friend and then checking if he is a friend or not? But you say `loop that checks for friend requests, if there are any, it accepts them` which is contradictory to your code.

Comment: What I'm trying to do, (or am doing) is the following: You can only see friend requests by s.get_snaps(), then I filter the results so that only type 3 show up, these are friend requests. I filter the name, and add the name with `s.add_friend(sender)` sender is the filtered name here. After that I want to check, how many people I can still add, since the limit is around 6000 (a little over actually) so I do a s.get_friends() and filter results with the type 0 (confirmed friends), I do a count with len, and print the amount of people added vs max.

Comment: Why don't you just put the whole bottom section of your code under the "if sender == 3"? That way it only runs after you add a friend.

Comment: Nope it spams my command line full with 5 / 6000, it keeps going

Comment: nvm I'm throwing this, too much effort. Snapchat just has a crappy api. Now all of the sudden my other accounts start showing up as friendrequests again. so I have to filter them by checking if they are already confirmed and whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minimize the number of calls to snapchat, I would factor out the `s.get_friends()` call so it only does it when the script runs:

```py
import time

total_friends = len([friend for friend in s.get_friends() 
                     if friend['type'] == 0])

SLEEP_TIME = 60

while True:
    new_friends = 0
    snaps = s.get_snaps()
    for sender in snaps:
        if sender['media_type'] == 3:
            s.add_friend(sender[u'sender'])
            new_friends += 1

    total_friends += new_friends

    if new_friends:
        print 'Amount of confirmed friends:'
        print total_friends, '/ 6000'
    time.sleep(60)
```

This will get the current number of friends you have before ever entering the loop.  Then it gets (presumably new?) snaps, adds those of the proper `media_type` and increments `new_friends` at the same time.  If `new_friends` is not 0, it prints the new total number of friends.

Comment: Good thinking, but this way all friends will be listed, it may only list friends with type 0 (confirmed friends)

Comment: Whoops.  I meant to take care of that in `total_friends`.  In that case you could just do `len([friend for friend in s.get_friends() if friend['type'] == 0])`  A quick list comprehension to go over the friends in `s.get_friends()` and add them to a list if their `'type'` is 0.  Assign the whole shebang to `total_friends` and that should mimic what you have.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: NameError: name 'new_friends' is not defined

Comment: oops sorry, forgot a line, though the script is not working. it keeps summing up numbers, after 10 seconds it told me it had 47 confirmed friends, while there were only 5

Comment: The `get_snaps` and `add_friend` are completely opaque to me.  The code you've given only relates to retrieving data, making a couple of decisions based on the data received and then makes an announcement if applicable.  Does `get_snaps` just retrieve information received as of the last time `get_snaps` was invoked?  I don't know.  Does `add_friend` clear out some queue?  No idea.  As for the script just running over and over non-stop, you can add pauses.  Use `import time` and then `time.sleep(n)` where `n` is the number of seconds you want the script to wait before moving on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this solution will help you. You keep track of the first time you receive friends to avoid sending a message for your first run. Then you just compare the previous_friends to the current friends to indicate changes.

```
# Used to mark the initial receiving of the friends
friends_received = False
# Will store the names of all friends from the last loop
previous_friends = []

while True:
    new_friend = False
    snaps = s.get_snaps()

    for sender in snaps:
        if sender['media_type'] == 3:
            s.add_friend(sender[u'sender'])


    friends = s.get_friends()

    names = []
    for friend in friends:
        if friend['type'] == 0:
            names.append(friend[u'name'])

    # Checking if new friends have been received
    if friends_received and len(friends) > len(previous_friends):
        # New friends are available
        new_friend = True

    if new_friend:
        print "Amount of confirmed friends:",
        print len(names),
        print "/ 6000"

    # Keeping a record of the friends from the last loop
    if len(previous_friends) == 0:
        friends_received = True
    previous_friends = friends
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just doing this:

```
friendAdded = false
snaps = s.get_snaps()

for sender in snaps:
    if sender['media_type'] == 3:
        s.add_friend(sender[u'sender'])


friends = s.get_friends()

names = [];
for friend in friends:
    if friend['type'] == 1:
        names.append(friend[u'name'])
        friendAdded = true


if friendAdded == true:
    print "Amount of confirmed friends:",
    print len(names),
    print "/ 6000"
    friendAdded = false
```

Now it will only print when you add a new friend.

Comment: This won't work because the latter part of the script just looks up the confirmed friends, which will always be there, it looks up the friends just to get a number to print, hence `print len(names),`

Comment: The only way this will work is by adding an IF statement to it, to only execute, if once again, a friend or multiple friend requests are accepted, which brings us back to the original post. Thanks for looking with me though!

Comment: @Snowlav updated answer with your requirements...I think this is what you want.

Comment: What are these `;` at the end of some of your lines?

Comment: @Maxime Whoops! Been coding in `C#` all day :P

Comment: I've just tried the script, and it does not seem to be working, it keeps printing 4 / 6000 (since I have a total of 4 confirmed friends right now)

Comment: @Snowlav do you have the link for the Snapchat API you are using?

Comment: @Snowlav I think you want to change the `friend['type'] == 0:` to `== 1` since you are checking if the friend is `Unconfirmed` and then adding him/her.

Comment: No I'm checking for friends requests with media type 3, checking for confirmed friends to count how many I have. this is all very confusing haha